# How To Show StoredProcedure Result in MVC View

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am unable to fetch storedprocedure result from db and show in view . In DB Storedprocedure is working fine

**My StoredProcedure In MsSQL**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search]
    (
    @param1 varchar(max), 
    @param2 varchar(max),
    @param3 varchar(max),
    @param4 varchar(max)
    )
AS
BEGIN
select BusinessLogo,BusinessTitle,Details,ProfileUrl,Location,Country from ClientBusinesses where location like '%'+@param1+'%' and location like '%'+@param2+'%'
 and location like '%'+@param3+'%' and location like '%'+@param4+'%'
END
```

**Controller Code Where I am Executing StoredProcedure**

I tried Using Following Code But Facing But Can't See Data in ViewBag It gives Error on Foreach loop on ViewBag that column BusinessLogo does not exist but you can see in sp i am fetching BusinessLogo and similar error for other columns also

```
ViewBag listdata = db.Search(Country, state, city, str);
```

I also tried code below -

```
 List<ClientBusiness> listd=new List<ClientBusiness>();
 listd=db.Search(Country, state, city, str);
```

But it gives error

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PromoteMyName.ClientBusiness>'    F:\Desktop DATA\Desktop 23 Feb\PromoteMyName\PromoteMyName\Controllers\HomeController.cs    135 23  PromoteMyName
```

**In View I am Using Simple Code Below**

```
@foreach(var item in  ViewBag.listdata)
   {
}
```

Is this possible to pass  data fetched from sp to view via viewbag ?

Comment: You need to project your data into a model and pass a collection of that model to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you mean by viewmodel

Comment: I am using dbfirst approach . ClientBusiness is my table . If i use Select * in Storedprocedure can i pass clientbusiness modal to view

Comment: Is this possible to pass  data fetched from sp to view via viewbag

Comment: Yes, create a view model with the properties you want in the view and pass a collection of that model to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can I Use ClientBusiness Modal ( it is same table which i am fetching from db )

Comment: Yes you can, although if your view is for editing data, then a view model is always the better approach

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually My View is not for editing it only for Select Data from db and showing it

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the question details with what i was trying with ClientBusiness Entity

Comment: @Nathan Can I ask How?

Comment: @Nathan - I do not think it is. See this MSDN link on Sql Injection and Stored Procedures: [Do Stored Procedures Protect Against SQL Injection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection/). Steve is not creating a new string to execute but appending the % to the parameters which should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Do something similar to this, this is not exact solution but go along this lines.
1) Define your Viemodel to store the data from the StoredProc.

AddressModel.cs

```
public class AddressModel
{
    public string City {get; set;}
    public string State {get; set;}
}
```

AddressSearchResultModel.cs

```
public class AddressSearchResultModel
{
    public List<AddressModel> AddressResults {get; set;}
}
```

2) Once you get the data from storedproc, pass the data to the defined model.

```
var dataFromStoredProc=db.Search(Country, state, city, str);
// Translate the addressSerachResultModel to addressSearchResultModel
var addressSearchResultModel= new AddressSearchResultModel();
var addressModel= new AddressModel()
foreach(var item in dataFromStoredProc )
{
    //Assign every property from the dataFromStoredProc to     AddressModel
    //and add it to the list
    addressSearchResultModel.Add(AddressModel);
}
```

3) Lastly render the View from your viewmodel

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetResults()
{
    var dataFromStoredProc=db.Search(Country, state, city, str);

    // Translate the addressSerachResultModel to AddressSearchResultModel
    var addressSearchResultModel= new AddressSearchResultModel();
    var addressModel= new AddressModel()
    foreach(var item in dataFromStoredProc )
    {
        //Assing every property from the dataFromStoredProc to AddressModel
        //and add it to the list
        addressSearchResultModel.Add(AddressModel);
    }

    return View(addressSearchResultModel);       
}
```